# MediaWiki 1.27 VisualEditor extension not loading

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki, visual-editor, parsoid

We are running a private MediaWiki server used at our workspace for internal documentation. We recently installed the VisualEditor extension, along with the prerequisite Parsoid (v0.8.0) service and Stunnel (as our wiki is served through HTTPS). However, we are having the issue where the "Edit" tab for the visual editor will appear when a page is loaded, then suddenly disappear after about half a second.

We double checked that the extension settings in LocalSettings.php were properly set to automatically enable the VisualEditor interface, and make it default.

We first looked at the error logs for MediaWiki, as well as Parsoid, and there is nothing out of the ordinary. We made sure that the wiki API was available, and that Parsoid could reach it, and was working. We have also looked at the debug console in the browser for error messages, which was also silent as to the nature of the issue. We have tried all of the listed troubleshooting steps on both the Parsoid and VisualEditor pages, and all of the checks point to the service running without error.

When we inspected the source for the page, we noticed that the html tag had been assigned the class type "ve-not-available", which made us think that the extension was potentially loading (at least enough to assign this class), but that something was preventing it from working properly. It's just that something has left zero footprint in any logs or files that we can find.

We would like to know where to look next to potentially help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Do you see any failed API calls in the browser debug console?

Comment: What error are you seeing when you click the Edit button?

Comment: There are no errors in the console or any of the log files related to the Mediawiki services (like Parsoid). The page simply reloads and displays identically to how it was before.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, this issue has something to do with the Visual Editor not recognizing the current skin being compatible. Are you using a custom skin?

If so, try adding the following to your `LocalSettings.php`;

```
$wgVisualEditorSupportedSkins = ['MySkin'];
```